# Cannot sort using System.Linq.Dynamic

Tags: c#, linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

namespace LinqTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Sample> sampleData = new List<Sample>() 
            { 
                new Sample{ ID=1, Name="V", Designation="Executive", JoiningDate=DateTime.Now.Date, Salary=45000M },
                new Sample{ ID=2, Name="F", Designation="Executive", JoiningDate=DateTime.Now.Date, Salary=400M },
                new Sample{ ID=3, Name="A", Designation="Boss", JoiningDate=DateTime.Now.Date, Salary=5000M },
                new Sample{ ID=1, Name="D", Designation="Executive", JoiningDate=DateTime.Now.Date, Salary=2500M },
                new Sample{ ID=1, Name="V", Designation="Executive", JoiningDate=DateTime.Now.Date, Salary=45000M }
            };

            IQueryable<Sample> sas = sampleData.AsQueryable<Sample>();
            sas.OrderBy("Name");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see above, I am trying to do simple sorting on one of the column using `System.Linq.Dynamic` library's extension method. But it is not being sorted. When I hover over `sas` I see the items in its original order. Can someone please tell me why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original `sas` variable remains unordered. You need to save the *result* of `OrderBy`:

```
var myOrderedSas = sas.OrderBy("Name");
```

Comment: And possibly save to list or array to avoid re-ordering data on each enumeration

Comment: @GrantWinney Thanks, it works. But when I am invoking `.OrderBy("Name")` is it returning another `IQueryable`? If so then why I did not get any compilation error for no assignment?

Comment: @Md.lbrahim because it is not a error to not use the result of a function (you may get a warning, but I am not sure). The only "non assignment" error the compiler will generate is if you try to use a variable before it is initialized.